# Database Query Issue #1242

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

Query Issue

I keep getting error: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

```
SELECT staffNumber, firstName, Surname, JobTitle
FROM Staff
WHERE branchNumber = (SELECT branchNumber
              FROM Branch
              WHERE city LIKE 'Portsmouth')
```

It works fine for my friend who has exactly the same code, but for some reason not me. :/
All help appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

That means your sub query is matching more than one result.

```
SELECT staffNumber, firstName, Surname, JobTitle
FROM Staff
WHERE branchNumber = (SELECT branchNumber
          FROM Branch
          WHERE city LIKE 'Portsmouth' LIMIT 1)
```

Or you can do something like this instead:

```
SELECT staffNumber, firstName, Surname, JobTitle
FROM Staff
WHERE branchNumber IN (SELECT branchNumber
          FROM Branch
          WHERE city LIKE 'Portsmouth')
```

Answer (score 0):

I Imagine this is a Data Issue wherin,

```
SELECT branchNumber
FROM Branch
WHERE city LIKE 'Portsmouth'
```

returns multiple rows.

a subquery used this way needs to return only one result. Depending on your data and what you are trying to accomplish, you can fix this with

```
SELECT branchNumber
FROM Branch
WHERE city LIKE 'Portsmouth' LIMIT 1
```

Or use `IN` instead of `=`